# Optimize zipcode distance calculation

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, geolocation, geospatial, computational-geometry

Here is the question I have for all

I already have an existing system that does the "Near By Zipcodes" search.

The purpose of this post is to see if I can optimize the process.

Currently, I have about 43k zipcode records.

The way my current algorithm works is I select 1 record and do a full table scan of 43k records.

Is there a way to only take a subset (lat range, long range) and do the calculation that way?

Comment: Your question is kind of vague. Are you asking about using the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get lat/lon for the centroids of all the zip codes from google, or geocoder.us (or wherever you get your geo data). Use them in your where clause as a rough guide to narrow your search.

Comment: I know.. but I dont know hwo to get the range example: point x(10,10) distance 10 then I can say select * From points p where p.x > 8 and p.x < 12 and p.y > 8 and p.y < 12 which will be a smaller list of records to compare distance for... I know geometry to know 8 and 12 are within range, how do I do that for lat long?

Comment: In the US, you can figure about 69 miles per degreee of latitude, and 52 miles per degree of longitude. Here is a neat calculator to check you own area http://www.ariesmar.com/degree-latitude.php.

Comment: what does that transfer into decimal (lat/long) values ?

Comment: 1.0 - if someone asks for items 50 miles from 41/87 (lat/lon), you can limit your query to looking at latitudes between 40 and 42, and longitudes between 86 and 88. You might need to use larger margins, to account for oddly shaped zip code areas and users who are near an edge of an area.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is bracket my searches plus and minus one degree. As mentioned, degrees latitude are about 69 miles. With longitude, things get a little more complicated. The closer you get to the North pole, the shorter the distance will be from one degree of longitude to another. For instance, at the Florida / Georgia border, one degree of longitude is about 55 miles apart, but at the California / Oregon border, it's only about 50 miles apart.

You first need to have the latitude / longitude for your starting location and probably want to set 4 variables such as: beglat, endlat, beglong and endlong. Assign the beglat to the starting location's latitude minus one degree, the endlat to the starting location's latitude plus one degree, etc. For a tighter search radius, you can choose half a degree or something else.